# What song is playing during Quicksilver's first appearance?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

When Professor X and the others first meet Quicksilver in his basement in [*X-Men: Days of Future Past*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877832/), there is a song playing in the background.

Anyone know what that song is, and why it might have been chosen for the scene?

Comment: not sure but isn't this a duplicate of a question asked before? There was a whole discussion on the use of soundtrack tag and so on?

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - actually although I can understand why you think so, this is not a duplicate.  The other question asked about the song playing in the prison break scene.  The meta discussion about whether this sort of question is on topic, seems to fall on the side of keeping them.  I'll edit the question anyway to nudge it in the right direction anyway.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - then there's the other question asking about the song playing on Wolverine's first appearance in the '70's.  Clearly they did something right with the choice of music in this movie if its attracting so much attention.

Comment: Hit this link and you got the answer! ;) http://www.what-song.com/Movies/Soundtrack/1427/X-Men-Days-of-Future-Past

Answer (score 3):

Finally got around to it... A deleted answer did mention Alice Cooper but without specifying a title, so here's the full answer. The song playing in this scene is Alice Cooper's [Hello Hurray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Hooray) from the 1973 album *Billion Dollar Babies*. You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rla3FCarWYU). As for its significance (other than establishing 'cool' and '1973'), some of the lyrics could describe Quicksilver's getting out of that basement and utilizing his talent for real after being recruited by the X-men:

> "Let the show begin
>
> I've been ready
>
> ...............
>
> I've been waiting so long for this thing to come
>
> I've been thinking so long I was the only one
>
> Roll out your American dream and its recruits, I've been ready
>
> Roll out your circus freaks and hula hoops, I've been ready
>
> ...............
>
> I'm so strong"